# download server iran

Tags: downloads

I have ubuntu 13.04 and my problem is this:

When i installed it i chose my location to be iran and ubuntu found a download server in iran for me.

But a few days ago i changed my download server to one in us.

Now i want to set it back to iran. but i can not find it. and when i choose ubuntu to find the best server it finds one in england, sweden, ...

I have problem with downloading from these servers.

Pleast help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no official Ubuntu full mirror site in Iran. There is one in Iran for the CD ISO image, which you can find [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+mirror/yazd-university). Otherwise, your best option is to open Software Sources, and in the "Download from:" pop-up list, click on the "Select Best Server" button to access the server with the best current response time.

Comment: Could you detail a bit more what do you mean by "open Software Sources"?